# Did Dhritarashtra really give death punishment to Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

StarPlus Mahabharat ([S11 E6](https://www.hotstar.com/tv/mahabharat/s-28/punishment-for-arjun/1000011884)) has a scene that shows that after their first exile when the Pandavas return to Hastinapura with Draupadi, Duryodhana insults Draupadi saying how can a woman that can have relationships with 5 men know dharma herself or teach dharma to her husbands. Upset with these words Arjuna draws his bow threatening to behead Duryodhana but Karna comes to the rescue.

For raising a weapon in the assembly, Dhritarashtra announces death punishment to Arjuna but Yudhishthira challenges this decision.

Is there a scriptural basis for this incident?

Comment: Which tv serial? I don't remember watching such things in BR Chopra's Mahabharata...

Comment: @YDS in Star Plus serial.

Answer (score 1):

So far as my knowledge NO. There was a story about how he tried to crush Bhima after the war for single handedly killing all his sons. But this is a null point, since Mahabharata has many interpretations & adaptations. Not to mention the Lore, stretching back before the Pandavas & long after their Deaths is littered with Several side stories that may differ regionally. Some could've been addition by regional writers to strengthen their cultural familiarity to the epic. or even cautionary tales.

But generally not a good idea to take anything sourced from the idiot box. the half a dozen adaptations today take far too 'creative liberties' to boost interest. they don't have the authenticity of the 1988 versions. (well as much authenticity as for a TV show)

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE!.Although your answer is somewhat right  It will be better if you add some  sources in your answer from the web as it is mandatory on this site to add some. You can also take help of some web sites mentioning this if any for this answer only. Otherwise we have to provide sources from authentic  Hinduism only.